# rewrite URL with mod-rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've to change my URL from

`http://mysite.com/shtml/home.shtml`

to

`http://mysite.com/home.shtml`

using mod-rewrite.

I tried something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^\/shtml\/(.*)$ /$1
```

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 2):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^shtml/(.+)$ /$1 [L,R,NC]
```